# How can I access to my own localhost with port number in powershell?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I am writing a script in PowerShell that will automate some actions within an application which is running on my localhost port 81. I need to access this application's content via PowerShell so I can edit and save it.

I learnt a lot about PSSession, but the app I'm trying to reach is on my own machine, not remote. Is there a way to do this?

---

Edit:

The application I'm trying to reach is TeamCity. I set its port to 81 and to access the application I just need to type `http://localhost:81` in my web browser to open TeamCity's UI.

I learnt the process of creating a new project and its builds through the application itself, but by doing so some files are created somewhere and that's what I'm trying to do programmatically:

```
nsn -ComputerName localhost -port 81 -Credential Get-Credential
```

I get this error :

> nsn : [localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with
>   the following error message: The WinRM client cannot process the
>   request. It cannot determine the content type of the HTTP response
>   from the destination computer. The content type is absent or invalid.
>   For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help
>   topic.At line:1 char: 1
>   + nsn -ComputerName localhost -Port 81 -Credential Get-Credential
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession],
>   PSRemotingTransportE     xception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108297,PSSessionOpenFailed

I also tried in vain `set-location http://localhost:81` but got the error saying the path is not a drive (knew it already).

Comment: Voting to put on hold as 'unclear what you're asking'. It depends what the application is, and what it means that it's "running on port 81". Because it's so close to port 80, I imagine it's a webservice and yes you can connect to a webserver on your local machine (if the firewall rules allow you to). But then what does PSSession have to do with that?
 And/or how will accessing its content help you automate it? Please edit your question and add some details of what you're doing, what you've tried, and how it didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though the context of what you're trying to do is lacking, you should be able to just use "http://localhost:81" as your url vs an actual web address. PSSession's wouldn't apply here, since you're (likely) not remoting (completely unable to tell though due to lack of details)

edit: thanks for updating your answer. I haven't used TeamCity before, but I'm pretty familiar with Git and TFS, and neither of those would have you connect over WinRM. Also, you wouldn't be able to connect over WinRM to your localhost, as that negates the purpose of Windows *Remote* Management. If you know what commands you are trying to run after entering the `New-PSSession` (`nsn`), just run those and skip starting the PSSession.

I am pretty sure the only commands you'd need to do with TeamCity are git or git-like, which would be outside of Powershell. Otherwise, you'd be going through some sort of API call over http/https and not through WinRM. If you're trying to manage the server that TeamCity is on, that's a different story that brings me back to my point about not needing WinRM because you don't need to remotely manage a server that you're already on, you just manage it directly.

Comment: After thoughts I found a way to create, edit and delete TeamCity projects with PowerShell by directly accessing its data directory on the hard drive. Mine was located at C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\projects. In case anyone is looking for a way to manipulate TeamCity projects through PowerShell instead of REST API or any other API.